# Xcode .m file mysteriously converted to binary

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

On OSX Mountain Lion Xcode 4.6

One of my .m files seems to have been converted to binary charset.  I have no idea how/why or how to fix it.  Please help!

this is the return with $file -I

```
MobileWebclock.m: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

When I open the file in a text editor it looks something like this:

```
—o%`dÈ!Œ.nÙ²EöÚÐ£PäABdæ
6l(//±ókzß¶mP\ÖÎ
```

Also Xcode says the encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: Use a hex dump program to see what the file looks like inside.

Comment: hexdump doesn't really give any helpful info.

Comment: If I had a backup this wouldn't be a problem :/

Comment: Well, then you'll just have to remember what you typed.  (NB: Be sure to 'clean' the project, and probably reboot your box, before you start back into this.  You want to avoid it happening again.)  (And DVDRs are cheap.)

Comment: I guess I'll just have to retype it...  Still a bit unsettling on how something like this just happens...

Comment: The Xcode editor has always seemed a bit unstable to me.

Comment: (You might want to look around in the directories -- use ls -a to see hidden files, etc -- to see if maybe there's a temp copy of your file stashed somewhere.)

Comment: In 3 years of using Xcode every day, I've not seen this happen. But if there's a lesson here, it's: use source control. Always.

Answer (score 1):

You can try converting it back at [this online tool](http://i-tools.org/charset).

You may also be able to grab an old version from your source control system.

You can use `file` without the `-I` parameter to see what the file type might be - perhaps you zipped it or saved an image over that file by accident.

Finally, if you have a compiled version, you can try your hand at decompiling it.  http://www.ohloh.net/p/i386codedump and https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml are good places to start.  Also try out `otool -tV file`.  Also, I came across Hopper (http://hopperapp.com/) which I haven't used but looks promising.

Comment: The online tool didn't help, I don't have an older version unfortunately, and file without -I just says "data".

Comment: Updated with some decompiling options, although @hot-licks 's suggestion to just retype it may be better.